# Can't get TextView's value in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

In `ListView` I have list of `LinearLayout`s(LL). Each `LinearLayout`(LL) have 2 `LinearLayout`s(LL1 and LL2). And the second `LinearLayout`(LL2) have`TextView` I want get `TextView`'s value in `LinearLayout` via `OnButtonCliclListener`

Here is code of my Adapter:

```
int resource;
TextView tt;
LinearLayout LL;
LinearLayout LL2;
LinearLayout LL1;
TextView currentText;
public Vk_row_adapter(Context _context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int _resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(_context, data, _resource, from, to);
    this.results = data;
    context = _context;
    resource = _resource;


}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    LL= (LinearLayout)v.getRootView();
    LL1 = (LinearLayout)LL.getChildAt(0);
    LL1.setOnClickListener(onButtonClickListener);
    LL2 = (LinearLayout)LL.getChildAt(1);
    LL2.setOnClickListener(onButtonClickListener);
    currentText = (TextView)LL2.getChildAt(0);

    tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vk_name);
    tt.setText((CharSequence) results.get(position).get(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT_NAME));

    //other elements

    return v;
}
private View.OnClickListener onButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
     Toast.makeText(context, currentText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
};
```

It gives me only the last TextView's text. I know why. But I don't know to make it correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Really...

You have one variable storing the current text for LL2 and non storing it for LL1, yet you are using the same onclicklistener for both...

There are several solutions here, lets go with the make a second variable and onclicklistener for simplicity

Comment: I made it specially, because they execute the same functionality

Comment: not quite, they make different toasts. There is probably a way to get the view that set off the listener dynamically and put the correct string in maketext. try google, either way you need to save or be able to access both texts .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sollution

```
public class Vk_row_adapter extends SimpleAdapter {
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT_NAME = "text_name";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT_RAITING = "text_place";
final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE = "image";
private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> results;
Context context;
String Name=null;
int resource;
TextView tt;
LinearLayout LL;
LinearLayout LL2;
LinearLayout LL1;
TextView currentText;
public Vk_row_adapter(Context _context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int _resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(_context, data, _resource, from, to);
    this.results = data;
    context = _context;
    resource = _resource;


}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
    LL= (LinearLayout)v.getRootView();
    LL.setOnClickListener(onButtonClickListener);
    tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vk_name);
    tt.setText((CharSequence) results.get(position).get(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT_NAME));

    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.vk_raiting);
    bt.setText((CharSequence) results.get(position).get(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT_RAITING));

    ImageView vt = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.vk_photo);
    vt.setImageBitmap((android.graphics.Bitmap) results.get(position).get(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE));

    return v;
}
private View.OnClickListener onButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LinearLayout asd = (LinearLayout)view;
        LL2 = (LinearLayout)asd.getChildAt(1);
        currentText = (TextView)LL2.getChildAt(0);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(currentText.getText())
                .setMessage("Перейти на страницу Вконтакте?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton("Да",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            }
                        }).create().show();
    }
};

private String getName()
{
    int i = Top_Tab2.VkRowListView2.indexOfChild(tt);
    return String.valueOf(i);
}
```

}